# Can I start an AsyncTask through a share activity, without displaying the activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, background, android-asynctask, share

The question is pretty much in the title. I want to know if I can start and execute an AsyncTask or something else in the background with the Intent data from the share activity, without actually launching the share activity. I looked for some information, but the only thing I found is how to register a service with your app, which isn't really what I was looking for. Bonus question: can I also display a notification or a small disappearing textbox on the display upon the AsyncTask completion/addition

To avoid confusion, this is what I mean with share activity:

```
<activity android:name=".ShareActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: the event is triggered when a user wants to share something with my app like this http://www.guidingtech.com/assets/postimages/2012/12/cloudsend-to-share-files-on-Android-1.png. Basically through the normal share context menu. Usually this will trigger the ShareActivity to be initiated, but I want to bypass that and execute some task without opening the ShareActivity of my app

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have your shared method in a separate class and then the activities can access it from there?

Just using psuedo code.

```
class MyTask {

    void myAsyncMethod (){
    }

}
```

and call it from your activities.

```
MyTask _myTask = new MyTask();

_myTask.myAsyncMethod();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think you're missing the point. I'm trying to bypass going through an Activity and straight up execute a method. I thought I can define a function to be ran in the manifest file instead of an activity, but alas, I found nothing.

Comment: I'm talking about the share activity, for example when you want to share a picture on facebook, but instead of showing an activity I want an AsyncTask to be executed, without showing the user anything. The only thing that comes close to solving my problem is to run the task and call the finish() method on the activity afterwards. I'll edit my question to include the part of the manifest to avoid further confusion.